# How to pass a session from one page to another one?

Tags: perl, session, cgi, session-cookies

I'm trying ot do a simple login using session on perl.

ON my login page I have which is wokring fine it create the session on "tmp"

```
use strict;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser/;
use CGI::Session ( '-ip_match' );
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my $cgi = new CGI; 


#create a new session
my $session = new CGI::Session("driver:File", undef, {Directory=>'/tmp'});




#store something
$session->param("valid","yes");

#write to disk
$session->flush();
```

But when I try to retrieve the session on a different page I can get the values stored in the session an it always create a new one. Can some one explainme what am I ding wrong;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser/;
use CGI::Session ( '-ip_match' );
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my $session = CGI::Session->new or die CGI::Session->errstr;

print $session->header();

my $days = $session->param("valid");
print $days;
print "<br><br>";

if ($session->is_empty) {
  print "Empty";
} else {
  print "Good";
}
```

Comment: CGI::Session requires a storage mechanism for persistence. As documented, the default is https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session::Driver::file. By default that stores in a temporary directory. This isn't the best idea for persistence. You also need to make sure both CGI::Session instances access the same storage.

Comment: Please also note that the CGI Perl module is not recommended for modern Perl web applications. Frameworks such as Mojolicious and Dancer2 have built in session persistence support, and can be deployed as CGI or in better ways. See http://blogs.perl.org/users/grinnz/2018/11/modern-perl-cgi.html